# intersection of two subspaces is not $\{0\}$

Tags: vector-spaces

If V and W are 3-dimensional subspace of $R^5$ then prove that V and W must have a nonzero common vector.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $V\cap W=\{0\}$ would imply $\dim(V+W)=6$.

Comment: Oh OK I understood. I am totally a beginner in linear algebra. We can prove it by contradiction. I'll answer my own question

Comment: because of duplication I can delete my question if you delete your answer @Berci